# How to pass arguments or params to Laravel Envoy task

Tags: php, laravel, docker-compose, laravel-envoy

I'm working on a Laravel project where we use `docker-compose` for the local development environment, and we are trying to shorten the commands that we use for installing composer dependencies and artisan with laravel/envoy. Here is an example of what we have done so far:

```
@task('composer-require')
   docker-compose exec -u 1000 web composer require {{ $package }}
@endtask
```

And use as follow
`envoy run composer-install --package=xxx/yyy`

And now our `Envoy.blade.php` file is getting to big because we have to put each usage as a task and we have to remember all those names.

I want to know if it is possible, how can we take a command like this `envoy run composer install xxx/yyy` and define only a task named `composer` and then pass the `install xxx/yyy` part?

Sory about my english

Answer (score 8):

You can pass the arguments like this `envoy run deploy --command=require --package=laracasts/flash.` You can also set defaults for `--package` and `--command` if you'd like. Where possible, use a deploy "story" rather than running one task at a time.

```
@servers(['web' => '127.0.0.1'])

@setup
    $package = isset($package) ? $package : "laravel/envoy";
    $command = isset($command) ? $command : "require";
@endsetup

@story('deploy')
    composer
@endstory

@task('composer')
    echo "Running: composer {{ $command }} {{ $package }}.";
    composer {{ $command }} {{ $package }}
@endtask

@finished
    echo "Envoy deployment complete.\r\n";
@endfinished
```

Comment: This is what I'm actually doing! I talked with Taylor Otwel and i found that is better to use something like bash to achieve my goals

Comment: @karl-hill Is there a way to pass a parameter to the @ task function? I am trying to centralize some code instead of duplicating functions, and passing params to the command line isn't what I really need here.